# Web Scrap PHP no funciona con un link

Tags: php, html, dom

Hola a todos estoy haciendo scrap a una pagina con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php'); //Libreria
$url = "https://www.exito.com/products/MP00550000000204/Televisor+LG+Led+43+Pulgadas+Full+HD+Smart+TV+43LJ550T"; //Link del producto
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$post = $html->find('p[class=price offer]', 0)->plaintext;
$resultado = str_replace ( ".0", '', $post);
echo $resultado;
?>
```

Si ejecuto el script con la URL que tiene asignada funciona y me muestra el siguiente precio: **1186900**

Pero si cambio  el link por este https://www.exito.com/products/0000225183192526/Carne+Res+Molida+En+Bandeja

Ya no me funciona, no me muestra nada.

Que estoy haciendo mal? Pues estos precios estan dentro de la misma etiqueta con la misma clase.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

NOTA: Para probar el script necesitan el simple_html_dom-php [descargar aqui](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

y Adicional esto es solo por probar, estoy aprendiendo esto y estoy ensayando justo con paginas como esta, no busco un fin especifico.

Gracias

Comment: Ya te diste cuenta que en la actual página de la carne el precio ya no aparece, debido a que está agotado.

Comment: Buscas algo concreto find('p[class=price offer]' y en la segunda página, no existe nada así, luego tienes que devolver 0 o false o lo que quieras para cuando no hay precio.

Comment: Es probable que ya tienes la respuesta al problema, se debe a que el sitio utilza Cookies para establecer la ciudad y de acuerdo a esto devuelve las respuestas, chequea el request que se hace al sitio con todo el encabezado. Muchos items como los de viveres y perecederos varian de precio entre ciudad y ciudad.